# Sum of a step function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Please help me to find the following summation
$$\sum_{m=0}^{N} \sum_{n=0}^N \sum_{i=0}^N \sum_{j=0}^N \mathbb{1}(m,n,i,j)$$
where
$1(m,n,i,j)= \left\{ \begin{matrix} 1 \qquad m+n=i+j \\0 \qquad \; \; \; \;\; \textrm{otherwise} \end{matrix}\right.$

Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that for any choice of $m,n,i$ there is exactly one $j$ such that $1(m,n,i,j) = 1$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yeah. I see this property. But I don't know how to reformulate the sum. Could you please give more hints?

Comment: Sure, you can replace the last sum $\sum_{j=0}^N$ by $1$, to get $\sum_{m=0}^N \sum_{n=0}^N \sum_{i=0}^N 1$.

Comment: Hint: If there is exactly one $j$ for each choice of $m$, $n$, $i$, then how many possible values of $(m,n,i,j)$ exist for which $1(m,n,i,j)=1$? (One helpful approach might be to ask how many ways you can choose a value for $m$, $n$, and $i$ separately, and see if you can figure out how to put those together)

Comment: My comment above is incorrect, I am leaving it as punishment...

Comment: @copper.hat why is your comment incorrect?

Comment: See Bungo's comment below. I will fix my answer after I finish eating my crow pie.

Answer (score 2):

Your indicator function is just a Kronecker delta $\delta_{m+n,i+j}$. The Kronecker delta admits an integral representation
$$
\delta_{a,b}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\xi}{2\pi}e^{i\xi (a-b)}\ ,
$$
therefore your sum is
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{N} \sum_{n=0}^N \sum_{i=0}^N \sum_{j=0}^N \mathbb{1}(m,n,i,j)=
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\xi}{2\pi}\sum_{m=0}^{N} \sum_{n=0}^N \sum_{i=0}^N \sum_{j=0}^N e^{i \xi (m+n-i-j)}
$$
$$
=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\xi}{2\pi}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{N} e^{i\xi m}\right)^2 \left(\sum_{j=0}^{N} e^{-i\xi j}\right)^2 =\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\xi}{2\pi}\left(\frac{-1+e^{i N \xi +i \xi }}{-1+e^{i \xi }}\right)^2\left(\frac{e^{-i N \xi } \left(-1+e^{i N \xi +i \xi }\right)}{-1+e^{i \xi }}\right)^2=\frac{1}{3} \left(2 (N+1)^3+N+1\right)
$$

Comment: I suspect distributions are not the most optimal way to approach this problem.

Comment: @copper.hat Disagree. The Kronecker delta and its integral representation is the most flexible and general way to proceed (combinatorial *ad hoc* observation may work for this *specific* case, but will fail miserably every time the constraint is slightly more complicated or involved).

Comment: While I value flexibility, when it comes at the price of correctness I find it has less utility.

Comment: Sounds of my words being eaten...

Comment: What do you exactly mean with 'at the price of correctness'? Is there a mistake in my derivation?

Comment: Read my next comment. Actually, I thought your answer was meant as a joke originally which was what prompted my first comment, then I realised that it was a real answer and I thought you had made a computational mistake, hence the second comment, then I wrote an incorrect answer, hence my third comment.

Comment: While your approach is rather cunning, it does depend on the nice factorisation in the second last line, so it is not apparent to me that it is any less ad hoc?

Answer (score 1):

Given any $m,i$ there are $N+1-|m-i|$ pairs $n,j$ such that $m+n=i+j$ and so
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{m=0}^N \sum_{i=0}^N \sum_{j=0}^N \sum_{n=0}^N 1(m,n,i,j) &=& \sum_{m=0}^N \sum_{i=0}^N ( N+1-|m-i|  ) \\
&=& (N+1)^3 - \sum_{m=0}^N \sum_{i=0}^N |m-i| \\
&=& (N+1)^3 - 2\sum_{m=0}^N \sum_{i=0}^m (m-i) \\
&=& (N+1)^3 - 2\left( \sum_{m=0}^N \sum_{i=0}^m m - \sum_{m=0}^N \sum_{i=0}^m i \right)\\
&=& (N+1)^3 - 2\left( \sum_{m=0}^N m (m+1) - \sum_{m=0}^N {1 \over 2} m (m+1) \right)\\
&=& (N+1)^3 -  \sum_{m=0}^N m (m+1)\\
&=& (N+1)^3 - {1 \over 3} N (N+1)(N+2)\\
&=& {1 \over 3} (N+1)(2N^2+4N +3)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Do you mean "at most one"? Suppose e.g. that $m=n = 0$ and $i=1$. Then there is no such $j$.

Comment: You are correct, I am wrong.

Comment: I repaired my answer, but it was messier than I had hoped.

Comment: (+1) It's a lot less messy than I would have expected, although I admit to lazily using Wolfram Alpha to verify the last two lines.